# Eloquent Query using Dynamic Model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent

I have this code which I am using to create a dynamic model  in laravel

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class CRUD extends Eloquent
{   
    public $collection ;

    function __construct($attributes = [],$collection ="" )
    {  
        parent::__construct($attributes);

  $this->collection = $collection;

    }

}
```

and  I call this class using this code

```
     $table='HW12345' ;
     $device_model = new CRUD([],$table);
     $device_model::limit(10)->get();
```

but this code return empty array .
if I put this code inside the constractor

```
echo $collection
```

it print the correct value

> HW12345

that mean model get the value of passed variable .

if I replaced the code

> $this->collection = $collection;

to

> $this->collection = 'HW12345';

it is working right without any problem and return data from collection HW12345
what is my wrong and why is that happening

Answer (score 0):

`$collection` is a protected property.

You do not need this declaration in your model:

`public $collection ;`

And I would also set the collection value before calling the parent constructor.

```
function __construct($attributes = [], $collection = "")
    {  
        $this->collection = $collection;
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
```

Because generally, the protected properties are declared before any construct happens.

It's also very strange to use Eloquent in this manner. You remove a lot of it's static and smart features by not declaring your Models ahead of time.

Ex: You cannot do:

`$results = Model::where('field', 'value')->get();`

`$newRecord = Model::create([values...]);`

etc.

Comment: thank you for reply , I set the properties before the parent constructor but still have same result, empty data

Comment: I making system that will connect to switches and get data from the switch , user need to insert switch's serial number, then the system will create a collection for every new switch , I am inserting every device's data in its own collection as the data is very big

Comment: It seems like your code should work. It could be a bug. I would suggest looking at the package provider's github for support.